# Corebluetooth to fetch device names using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I'm using CoreBluetooth framework in my iOS application to scan and connect to other bluetooth devices. I'm able to scan successfully for devices using below code:

```
var centralManager: CBCentralManager?
var peripherals = [CBPeripheral]()
centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
```

In the CBCentralManagerDelegate, I implemented below code:

```
extension ViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if (central.state == .poweredOn){
            self.centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

        if !peripherals.contains(peripheral) {
            let localName = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey]
            print("\(String(describing: localName))" )
            peripherals.append(peripheral)
            tableView.reloadData()            
        }
    }
}
```

From above code localName is always nil. Am I missing any code?

To add more info,
When I am scanning for bluetooth devices in my Mac, I'm able to see the names of the devices. But when I am scanning for bluetooth devices on my iPhone, none of them are listed.

I cross checked and made sure that I enabled blue tooth on 4 more devices with me (iPad, 2 Android Phones and 1 Android TV)

Comment: Check if `advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey]` exists before doing `peripherals.append(peripheral)`. The thing is that the advertisement packets can be done piece by piece (because of limitation size), and the full advertisement comes later.

Comment: Thanks @Larme, I'll add that check. I explored some other apps from iTunes and all of them are showing identifiers instead of names. Is it not possible to fetch the names of the devices in iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed in your code only source of name - instead of:

`let localName = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey]`

I use:

`let localName = peripheral.name`

and now I see name of BLE devices around me.

Comment: I tried that as well. For me peripheral.name is also nil

Comment: Just saying... This is a different piece of information. The "peripheral.name" comes from the physical device itself (e.g. name of Raspberry Pi or whatever) whereas the Local Name is a parameter to the BLE advertisement.

Answer (score 3):

Swift with core bluetooth library:

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber){

    let peripheralLocalName_advertisement = ((advertisementData as NSDictionary).value(forKey: "kCBAdvDataLocalName")) as? String

    if (((advertisementData as NSDictionary).value(forKey: "kCBAdvDataLocalName")) != nil)

         print(peripheralLocalName_advertisement)//peripheral name from advertismentData

         print(peripheral.name)//peripheral name from peripheralData

         peripherals.append(peripheral) 

         arrayPeripheral.append(advertisementData)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `didDiscoverPeripheral` callback unfortunately can return `nil` for `CBPeripheral` names and also the `advertisementData`'s local name for the very first callback your app gets after you start a scan.

If you know that the peripheral that you're working with *will* contain a local name in the Bluetooth advertisement packet, you can choose to ignore the first callback that contains a `nil` name.

```swift
// In didDiscoverPeripheral
guard let peripheralName = peripheral.name else { return }
print("Did discover peripheral: \(peripheralName), RSSI: \(RSSI)")
```